# parsing *.txt file С#

Tags: c#, парсер

Нужно сделать парсинг файла *.txt, который в свою очередь нужно разместить в GridControl, тоесть разделить на три колонки, примерно так:

```
    дата 1 колонка -2015-08-03 13:29:07,774
    клас 2 колонка - DbConfigurationFileProcesor
  описание 3 колонка -Creating mssql connection. Database: 195.150.13.211\sqlexpress User: esuite
```

код который парсит работает нормально только с первой и второй строкой, как сделать чтобы быстро парсило и добавляло остальной текст  с файла ?

```
 var dataList = new List<DataText>();

        bool laststrWasDate = false;
        DateTime da;

        foreach (var fil in path)
        {

            foreach (var item in File.ReadLines(fil))
            {

                var parse = item.Split(' ');
                if (laststrWasDate == false)
                {
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(parse[0], out da))
                    {
                        var ed = new DataText();
                        ed.TimeData = parse[0] + " " + parse[1];
                        ed.DataClasa = parse[2];
                        dataList.Add(ed);
                        laststrWasDate = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var text = dataList[dataList.Count - 1];
                    text.Discription = item;
                    dataList[dataList.Count - 1] = text;
                    laststrWasDate = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return dataList;
    }

    #region Validation
    /// <summary>
    ///     Validate
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="s"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static bool ValidateParsedString(string[] s)
    {
        if (s.Length == 3)//если строка поделилась на три части то, скорее всего это то что нужно
        {
            try
            {
                var d = DateTime.Parse(s[0], System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);//дополнительно проверяем, что первое в строке это дата.
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

file.txt

```
2015-08-03 13:29:07,774 DbConfigurationFileProcesor
Creating mssql connection. Database: 195.150.13.211\sqlexpress User: esuite
2015-08-03 13:29:08,375 ConnectionProvider
Available connections: 2

2015-08-03 13:29:12,785 ConnectionProvider
Available connections: 1
Connections in use: 1
ThreadId        Counter Transaction
10              1     No

2015-08-03 13:29:15,437 TranslationEntities
SELECT
    [Extent1].[LG_APP_ID] AS [LG_APP_ID],
    [Extent1].[LG_CODE] AS [LG_CODE],
    [Extent1].[LG_NAME] AS [LG_NAME],
    [Extent1].[LG_DESC] AS [LG_DESC],
    [Extent1].[LG_ID] AS [LG_ID],
    [Extent1].[LG_IS_ACTIVE] AS [LG_IS_ACTIVE],
    [Extent1].[LG_LOCALIZATION_CODE] AS [LG_LOCALIZATION_CODE]
    FROM [dbo].[DI_LANGUAGES] AS [Extent1]
2015-08-03 13:29:15,438 TranslationEntities


2015-08-03 13:29:15,444 TranslationEntities
-- Executing at 2015-08-03 13:29:15 +02:00
```

Что я делаю не так ? если брать регулярные выражения то очень долго парсит

Comment: Не плодите новые вопросы - отредактируйте оригинальный. Если вас не устроило решение - не отмечайте его как правильный ответ.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [парсинг файла \*.txt c#](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/440095/%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-txt-c)

Answer (score 0):

нужно было только сделать конкатенацию строк

```
       var dt = new DataText();
                if (DateTime.TryParse(parse[0], out da))
                {
                    dt.TimeData = parse[0] + " " + parse[1];
                    dt.DataClasa = parse[2];
                    dt.TypeFiles = Path.GetFileName(fil.Split('.')[0]);
                    dataList.Add(dt);

                }
                else
                {
                    var text = dataList[dataList.Count - 1];
                    text.Discription += item;
                    dataList[dataList.Count - 1] = text;
                    laststrWasDate = false;
                }
```